# Stop ping between hosts in different sites

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have set 4 EC2 hosts in different regions (North Virginia, Oregon, California, and Ireland). Initially, I could ping all hosts using the internal IP, but then suddenly, I couldn't ping hosts in different sites. I just can ping the hosts with the external IP. As a network rule, my hosts accept all inbound traffic. I would like to understand what is going on? Is this a problem due to my network rules (accept all inbound traffic)? How can I debug this problem?

Comment: Internal IP is only valid within a given region, its not available outside of the region. Are you trying to use the internal IP outside of the region?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way you could have pinged the inter region hosts using private IPs. Private IPs are local to your VPC which cannot span across regions. The only way you could have done that is using VPNs and non-overlapping VPC CIDRs. So check if your VPNs are running and the routes are propagated correctly. Check your VPN security groups are set correctly and the VPC subnet route table.

It is very difficult to identify the issue with the information you have given.

Comment: The VPC is used to have IP Sec, but I don't want tunnels. I just want to communicate between sites. Is it possible to do it without VPC?